# Search for variables with strictly 0/1 data and convert them to factor with Yes/No in R and dplyr/tidyverse/pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have

```
  df <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
  var2 = c("1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0"),
  var3 = c("1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "3", "1"),
  var4 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3),
  var5 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"),
  var6 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Maybe")
)
```

I would like to search for all variable with **strictly** and **only** `0`/`1` values and convert them as factors with `"No"`/`"Yes"` labels.

My attempt was

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(where(unique(.) == c("0", "1")), 
                .fns = ~factor(ifelse(., "Yes", "No"), levels = c("Yes", "No"))))
```

but it does not seem to work.

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while evaluating `where(unique(.) == c("0", "1"))`.
Caused by error in `where()`:
! Can't convert `fn`, a logical matrix, to a function.
```

I seek a solution within the `tidyverse` / `dplyr` `pipe` system. I do not want to specify which variable to search or convert.

In the above example only `var1` and `var2` should be converted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(where(~ all(.x %in% 0:1)), factor, labels = c("No", "Yes")))

  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5  var6
1   No  Yes    1    0  Yes   Yes
2  Yes  Yes    1    0   No    No
3   No   No    0    1  Yes   Yes
4  Yes   No    0    1   No    No
5  Yes  Yes    1    1  Yes   Yes
6   No  Yes    3    0   No    No
7  Yes   No    1    3  Yes Maybe
```

Comment: i can understand the logic of your answer. Thank you very much. I don't understand why you need. the ~ symbol. What does this mean? Why is it needed? why cant the same code run without the ~? The first argument of where is the check function. Why do you need the ~ symbol? Would you mind dropping a comment please?

Comment: `~` in this context is the rlang lambda function, a shorthand for creating anonymous functions.  See https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#purrr-shortcuts for more detail.